# Two radio buttons related in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

How can I translate this to Ionic 2 ?

```
<div class="weightunitradios">
  <ion-checkbox 
    class="checkboxes" 
    ng-model="data.weightunit" 
    ng-true-value="'kg'" 
    ng-false-value="'lbs'" 
    ng-change="saveWeightUnit(); changeMinMax(); convertWeightInput(); saveUserWeight();">
    kg
  </ion-checkbox>
  <ion-checkbox 
    class="checkboxes" 
    ng-model="data.weightunit" 
    ng-true-value="'lbs'" 
    ng-false-value="'kg'" 
    ng-change="saveWeightUnit(); changeMinMax(); convertWeightInput(); saveUserWeight();">
    lbs
  </ion-checkbox>
</div>
```

I tried this but the behavior is not what I expected, I need to be able to select only one radio at a time :

```
<ion-list class="weightunitradios">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>kg</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox 
      mode="ios" 
      value="kg" 
      [(ngModel)]="data.weightunit" 
      ngTrueValue="'kg'" 
      ngFalseValue="'lbs'" 
      (ionChange)="saveWeightUnit(); changeMinMax(); convertWeightInput(); saveUserWeight();">
    </ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>lbs</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox 
      mode="ios" 
      value="lbs" 
      [(ngModel)]="data.weightunit" 
      (ionChange)="saveWeightUnit(); changeMinMax(); convertWeightInput(); saveUserWeight();">
    </ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: One of the changes should be to create a function that calls `saveWeightUnit(); changeMinMax(); convertWeightInput(); saveUserWeight();` and then calling this function on `ionChange`

Comment: can't I put several functions in the ionChange event ?

Comment: Yes, you can. No doubt about it. But I personally feel that it is a bad practice to do so. Your template should be as clean as possible. And most of the logic should be inside your component instead of your template.

That promotes maintainability, a better separation of concerns, and it's better for Unit Testing as well.

Comment: Thanks @SiddharthAjmera that's a very good advice ! But what would you recommend, radio buttons ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess. But they won't look really good. For the same, you'll have to customize them per your needs.